# Subsetting data based on a factor level selected by two column ID's in R

Tags: r, shiny, data-manipulation, r-plotly

So I have data that is somewhat similar to this.

```
f1 <- data.frame(MY = c("18-1", "18-1",
                        "18-2", "18-2","18-2","18-2","18-2",
                        "18-3", "18-3","18-3"), Factor = c(1,1,1,2,3,3,2,3,1,1), More_Data = 1:10)

f1 <- f1 %>% group_by(MY) %>% mutate(ID = row_number() - 1)


   MY    Factor More_Data    ID
   <fct>  <dbl>     <int> <dbl>
 1 18-1       1         1     0
 2 18-1       1         2     1
 3 18-2       1         3     0
 4 18-2       2         4     1
 5 18-2       3         5     2
 6 18-2       3         6     3
 7 18-2       2         7     4
 8 18-3       3         8     0
 9 18-3       1         9     1
10 18-3       1        10     2
```

I want to select an ID based on MY and get all rows correlated to Factor in the whole data set.

So if I select ID 1 and it then correlates to MY 18-1 then I want a data set that looks like this by selecting the factor level.

```
   MY    Factor More_Data    ID
   <fct>  <dbl>     <int> <dbl>
 1 18-1       1         1     0
 2 18-1       1         2     1
 3 18-2       1         3     0
 9 18-3       1         9     1
10 18-3       1        10     2
```

Notice I keep all the factors with 1 regardless of MY and ID.

My best attempt:

```
ID <- 1

f1[f1$Factor == f1$Factor[f1$ID == ID],]

  MY    Factor More_Data    ID
  <fct>  <dbl>     <int> <dbl>
1 18-1       1         1     0
2 18-2       1         3     0
3 18-3       1         9     1
4 18-3       1        10     2
```

My real dataset is much larger and this method is not even getting close.

More context to the problem:
I am doing this in `shiny` with `plotly` as a linked click. I am also doing this frame by frame (the MY factor). With a linked click you use event data and event data gives all the points in the plot on the frame for month and year I can then click a point and correlate this to the ID column that I made and if I select that ID it correlates to the factors I want. The problem is if the plot point correlates to 1, my code then quires all 1's in ID not just on that frame and then correlates all factors related to the last 1.

Comment: `f1 <- unique(rbind(subset(f1, MY=='18-1'), subset(f1, Factor==1)))`?

Comment: So im not sure this works for a changing MY also i need ID to be selcted first then the MY on that row and then the Factor is chosen

Comment: You can pass in a value to replace hard-coded `'18-1'`. And add a subset for ID into `rbind`: `f1 <- unique(rbind(subset(f1, ID=ID), subset(f1, MY==MY_Var), subset(f1, Factor==1)))`

Comment: No not quite it. Also factor could change with each mouse click. Basically when i click a point i get a pointNumber that is the point relating to a changing MY and a changing ID and I am tying to get all the observations of the correlating factor level value.